# Streamline mvc 4 project for optimal web api performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently reviewing ASP.NET Web API and wondered if anybody has managed to 'streamline' the VS2010/12 project template that you get when you create a new ASP.NET Web API project.

Call me skeptical, but I'm wondering if Microsoft have thrown a few things in the project template that might not be needed, whereby its removal will make the things go faster.

For example, in web forms, you get most of the http modules included by default, and in most cases you won't need all modules.

Basically, I'm looking for the best performance possible for my shiny new Web API webservice, and if I can throw out the spare tyre and the ashtray, I will.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There was a lot of [feedback](http://forums.asp.net/t/1771245.aspx/1) about getting a cleaner starting point for the purist developers. Release notes [here](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes):

> "Empty Project Template
>
> The MVC Empty project template is now truly empty so that you can
>   start from a completely clean slate. The earlier version of the Empty
>   project template has been renamed to Basic."

You will find that the "Empty" project template will be the minimum you can get away with on a new WebApi project.

File -> Templates -> Web - Asp.Net MVC 4 Web Application

Select Template "Empty".